# How is the python interactive shell connected to Django?

Tags: python, django, shell

Hello fellow programmers!

I am reading about the functionality of the interactive shell reached through running `...python manage.py shell`. This is something that I have done many times before, however I am not quite sure exactly How the actual shell connects with Django. Before asking this question, I have indeed tried to find my way through the official documentation - as well as other posts on this website. This question does not appear to have been presented with an answer a beginner like me can comprehend.

I have read that the `manage.py shell`-command 'gives us an interactive shell with the Python path set up correctly for Django.'. I know that it can be used to interact with a Django project, and to query configured databases and models - however what happens behind the scenes?

For example, when writing `ModelName.objects.all()` - what is the origin of `.objects` and `.all()`, because it does not seem to be pure python syntax? How does Django understand this?

Is the shell a special python-version provided by Django, with some added syntax that Django understands? Because that would make sense.

Thank you from Sweden!

Comment: The `.objects()` is more a consequence of metaclasses, etc.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `objects` and `all` work just as well in your server code as they do in the shell. And they're just standard attributes, anyway. Why do you think this has anything to do with the shell?

Comment: That was my guess, since it was not pure python syntax. My guess was that it was django database API, which is something that I have heard a couple of times. Is that correct? If so, what does that mean?

Comment: It's perfectly normal Python syntax, so again I don't know what you mean. The Model class defines an `objects` attribute which is a Manager, which has a method `.all()`. There is nothing special about this.

Comment: I may have used the wrong word to describe what I wanted to say, apologies for that. What I meant to say was that I have never seen '.objects'  etc outside of a Django context, not that the syntax was incorrect. I now understand that they are inherited from the Model class which makes perfect sense. What exactly is the Django database API? Could you help me make the connection between the shell and the API that I have read so much about? Many thanks, w

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, `objects` comes from the model having a manager.
[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/):

> A Manager is the interface through which database query operations are provided to Django models. At least one Manager exists for every model in a Django application.

Managers exist in django. So when you run the shell, you're just executing python code inside an environment that has django installed. You probably noticed that you have to run `from .models import myModel`, which means that having models (i.e. django code) isn't inherit to the shell, you need to manually import it.

A shell is just an interactive way of executing code. The only special thing from running it from `manage.py` is that it will have django and the rest of your packages in its PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Can someone confirm the thing I said in the last sentence...?